# Change behavior of Steps React component from Ant Design(https://ant.design/components/steps/)

Tags: reactjs, antd

As in the link example, I would like to change the behavior of Steps react component from ANT design to just color and select(highight) only on the step that is click(as oppose to now it colors all the previous steps also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make use of the `status` [prop in Step](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/a4d7593ef2bb6b9fd861b069f996e90aa98bdf25/components/steps/index.tsx#L27).

[Documentation](https://ant.design/components/steps/#Steps.Step)

[Example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/throbbing-shape-2mp8s)

Intead of:

```
  <Steps current="2">
     <Step title="INSTRUCTIONS" />
     <Step title="REGISTRATION" />
     <Step title="VERIFICATION" />
  </Steps>
```

[image]

use `status` **wait** on previous steps:

```
  <Steps current="2">
     <Step status="wait" title="INSTRUCTIONS" />
     <Step title="REGISTRATION" />
     <Step title="VERIFICATION" />
  </Steps>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually also wanted to do that dynamically when I have a number of tabs that show different steps and I can go can click on any step in any tab and should be able to show only that as selected. I could think of storing these step objects and do the calculation and set status prop. But I feel if I had a better way. TIA

Comment: @user578219 you can upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful. In the example you are describing you'll have to go via the state or props and a parent-child component relationship. I you have a concrete example/question I suggest you post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a prop available for `status` in Step component. It overrides highlight by current variable.  You can use that.
E.g:

```
  <Steps current={this.state.current} progressDot={customDot}>
    <Step
      title="Finished"
      status={0 < this.state.current ? "wait" : null}
      description="You can hover on the dot."
    />
    <Step
      title="In Progress"
      status={1 < this.state.current ? "wait" : null}
      description="You can hover on the dot."
    />
    <Step
      title="Waiting"
      status={2 < this.state.current ? "wait" : null}
      description="You can hover on the dot."
    />
    <Step
      title="Start"
      status={3 < this.state.current ? "wait" : null}
      description="You can hover on the dot."
    />
  </Steps>,
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually also wanted to do that dynamically when I have a number of tabs that show different steps and I can go can click on any step in any tab and should be able to show only that as selected. I could think of storing these step objects and do the calculation and set status prop. But I feel if I had a better way. TIA

Comment: Yes, that would be necessary,  as each tab will have a different step component. You would have to maintain separate state variable for each step component.